# passing arg 1 of `foo' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers

warning: passing arg 1 of `printTokens' from incompatible pointer type

```
void printTokens(const char** tokens);
char** readTokens(FILE* stream);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    char** tok = readTokens(fp);
    printTokens(tok);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

what's wrong? the paramter `tok` is `char**` and `printTokens` receives `char**`

Comment: No, `printTokens` receives `const char **`. That's the subtlety.

Comment: See also (linked from an answer on the essentially-duplicate question): http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const char**` and `char**` are not the same because of `const`, but you can use type cast.

So change

```
     printTokens(tok);
```

to

```
     printTokens((const char**)tok);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify what you pass to `printTokens()`, e.g.:

```
printTokens(const char **)tok);
```